# Create a 3D polyhedron from 2D convex polygon in bullet physics

Tags: computational-geometry, bulletphysics, bullet

I have a convex polygon in Oxy plane (defined by some vertices and edges). I would like to create a 3D polyhedron from extruding this polygon in z axis for some distance *h*. How can I do this in bullet physics?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The extrusion is simple to do by hand. For each vertex in the polygon you duplicate it, and set the Z value to the distance *h*. Then you can create a `btConvexHullShape` from the points in the set. Since it's a convex hull and not a triangle mesh you don't need to worry about the face information. If you look at the `btConvexHullShape` constructor you'll notice it only takes a list of points as the parameter.